# Is there a way to get the ISTEXT formula to ignore if there is a formula is the reference cell?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a simple formula:

=IF(ISTEXT(A3),"EA"," ")

I just need the cell with this formula to return EA is there is text in A3.  The problem is the column A is feeding off of another sheet so each cell has a formula in it.  My ISTEXT formula keeps returning EA even though the cell itself is blank.  I'm guessing this is due to the cell having a formula in it.  Any ideas how to make the ISTEXT ignore formulas?

Answer (score 2):

I'd just check the length of the cell:

```
=IF(LEN(A3)>0,"EA","")
```